# Getting only one id from duplicate ids (all having diffrent values) and updating the unique id with only one value (applying condition)

Tags: sql

I cant seem to solve this. I need to apply 2 conditions here - 
1) when the same id has both values as 'Bachlors' and 'Masters', I need to have the id only once and it shows bachelors.
2)when the same id has both values as 'Bachlors' and 'Masters' and 'PHD', I need to have the id only once and it shows bachelors.

id         degree 
1           bachelor
2           master
3           bachelor
1          master
2           bachelor 
2            phd

I want result like this - 
1        bachelor
2        master 
3        bachelor

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why should 2 be master and not bachelor? "when the same id has both values as 'Bachlors' and 'Masters' and 'PHD', I need to have the id only once and it shows bachelors."

Comment: Since people who have done both bachelors and masters university from the same xyz university, need to be put into bachelors. All this needs to be done so that we dont have the same person 2 times in data with different degrees. We will put him in bachelors.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when degree = 'Bachelors' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Bachelors'
             else max(degree)
        end)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: thank you so much Mr. Linoff. Now what I am not able to do is to update the records permanently. I am trying this......                      Update t
  Set Degree = (case when sum(case when [Degree] = 'Bachelors' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Bachelors'
             else max(Degree)
        end)
  group by [id]

Comment: @HarsHGuptA . . . If you have a question about updates, you should ask a separate question.